# Automorphisms of $D_{2n}$

Tags: group-theory

Let $D_{2n}$ be presented as $\langle r, s \mid r^n=s^2=1, srs=r^{-1}\rangle$. Is it the case that sending $r$ to any power of $r$ relatively prime to $n$ and sending $s$ to any reflection gives an automorphism, making $|Aut(D_{2n})|=n\phi(n)$? In addition, what is the structure of the automorphism group?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's correct. When $n>2$, the cyclic rotation group is characteristic, so all automorphisms have that form. The automorphisms that map $r$ to $r$ form a normal cyclic subgroup $N$ of order $n$. The subgroup that maps $s$ to $s$ forms a non-normal subgroup $U$ of order $\phi(n)$ isomorphic to the automorphism group of $N$, The complete automorphism group of $D_{2n}$ is the semidirect product $N \rtimes U$ (also known as the *holomorph* of $N$).

Comment: Ah, semi-direct product, that's it. Thank you!

Comment: Ah, so it's the holomorph of a cyclic group, which is the semidirect product of $C_n$ and its automorphism group.

Answer (score 1):

To check if some map is a homomorphism, it suffices to check that the generators satisfy the same defining relations. Then it will be an automorhpism because bijectivity holds.

Sending $r\mapsto r^k$ where $k \not\mid n$ satisfies $(r^k)^n=1$.

Sending $s\mapsto sr^m$ (another reflection) satisfies $(sr^m)^2=1$.

Finally, $$((sr^m)(r^k))^2=sr^{m+k}sr^{m+k}=ssr^{-m-k}r^{m+k}=1.$$

So yes, it seems that this map $\phi$ that you defined is an automorphism.

You also claim that all automorphisms take that form. I think that this is true with the exception of $D_2 \simeq C_2 \times C_2$ (the Klein 4-group), which has some other automorphisms since the elements of order two are indistinguishable.

I'm not sure what the automorphism group is though...

Disclaimer: I don't have much experience with algebra, so please correct me if I have said anything wrong!

Comment: Yeah, $D_4 \cong C_2 \times C_2$ is a special case.